# IIS Express Crashing when Closing Developer Dialog in Brave Browser

Tags: asp.net, tcp, iis-express, brave

I am using Windows 10 Pro, and am running a .NET Core 3.1 application on top of IIS Express 10.0.1741 in Visual Studio 2019, version 16.7.6.

I have created a Razor page to upload a file with the exact code from this blog:
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/file-upload

Setup for the issue: run the program (debug or release), navigate to the page using Brave browser (normal or private), and open the file upload dialog window.

Everything is fine at this point.

When the file dialog is closed, either by selecting a file or by hitting cancel, IIS Express crashes with exit code -1.

There is an error message in the Event Log:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft Security Client
Date:          11/2/2020 11:20:08 AM
Event ID:      5000
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      ****
Description:
The description for Event ID 5000 from source Microsoft Security Client cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

0x1
ProtectionManagement

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft Security Client" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">5000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-11-02T17:20:08.484614300Z" />
    <EventRecordID>39640</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>****</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>0x1</Data>
    <Data>ProtectionManagement</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

But I can not figure out how to resolve this issue.  I can't find logs, or dump files for IIS Express.

I have not been able to reproduce this on another Windows Server computer on the same network, with presumably the same security settings (though it is a server OS).

I have tried to sniff the packets using Fiddler, and there isn't a new HTTP packet that comes across when this happens, so it must be at a lower level on the IP stack (connection level maybe?)

I am worried about not understanding this, and it biting me again in the future.

Any ideas about what this might be?